# Why does my Simulink-Model rebuild at every iteration?

Tags: matlab, simulink, accelerator

I'am trying to speedup my simulink project and want to use the Accelerator-Simulation mode.

The aim of my project is to control a cyclic process and is structured as followes:

- matlab-script, where all parameters and a feedforward control with
  parameter estimation is implemented. Also it starts simulating the
  simulink model for each iteration.
- simulink model, where the dynamic system and the feedforward control (basically a lookup-table) together with a feedback control
  is implemented. Parameters of all blocks are set by workspace variables/structs generated by the script.

The feedforward control variable is calculated and parameter are estimated from the simulated data after every simulation pass. Then the model is simulated again. The model is not changing during the iterations, but still it is compiling at every cycle. From the first: **Is this solution appropriate for using the Accelerator mode?**

I tried to follow theses proposed steps to determine, why it is built at every iteration: [mathworks](http://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/examples/determining-why-simulink-accelerator-is-regenerating-code.html?refresh=true)

If i run it with the Accelerator-Mode (referring to the documentation of this function, it now compiles for simulation), I still cannot reproduce why it is compiled at every iteration.

```
csdet1.ContentsChecksum.Value ~= csdet2.ContentsChecksum.Value
```

is true, but the proposed code does not find any details.

```
csdet1.InterfaceChecksum.Value ~= csdet2.InterfaceChecksum.Value
```

is also true, the proposed code outputs that

```
UserDefinedTypesChecksum
```

is different. What does that mean and how can I resolve this?

Sidefact: When I run Simulink.BlockDiagram.getChecksum() with the Model opened in Simulink and Normal-Mode chosen, I get this error:

> Continuous update specified for this chart chartname This is not
>   supported for RTW."

But this chart is a Matlab-Function block, not a stateflow chart?!

Comment: Not sure about the rebuild issue, but note that MATLAB Function blocks are built on top of Stateflow technology, which in turn is really a (rather nice) way of drawing, rather than writing, an S-Function. That's why the error message refers to a chart.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, that explains the error message. Now I found the appropriate parameter to change the update method from "continuous update" to "inherited": in the matlab function editor/edit data it can be found.

However, the rebuild-issue still is not solved yet.